# MongoDB view with dynamic dates

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to create a view for records created/modified in last 24 hours.
Is it possible?

Tried creating view as below

```
db.createView(
   "viewname",
     "sourcecollection",
   [ { $match: {"modifiedTime":{$gte:new Date(Date.now() - 24*60*60*1000), $lte:new Date()}}}]
)
```

But it translates to static values

```
{
  modifiedTime: {
    $gte: ISODate('2022-10-25T23:20:21.602Z'),
    $lte: ISODate('2022-10-26T23:20:21.602Z')
  }
}
```

Did read about $$NOW but could not get it working in create view command.
Please suggest

Comment: What was the command you tried to run to create the view with $$NOW and what wasn't working about it? Did you get an error or?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
db.createView(
   "viewname",
   "sourcecollection",
   [
      {
         $match: {
            $expr: {
               $and: [
                  { $gte: ["$modifiedTime", { $dateSubtract: { startDate: "$$NOW", unit: "day", amount: 1 } }] },
                  { $lte: ["$modifiedTime", "$$NOW"] }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   ]
)
```

Comment: Hi, just observed the limitation. "$$NOW" works only within $expr and $expr does not use index. Is there any other alternatives?

Comment: Are you sure? Did you check the explain plan? Otherwise run a query instead of using a view.

Comment: Yeah, explain plain in compass shows that index is not used.  Documentation also says "$expr only uses indexes on the from collection for equality matches in a $match stage." https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.2/reference/operator/query/expr/

Comment: This limitation applies to `$lookup` stage only. Please show us your full match condition and/or the explain plan.

Comment: Explain plan snippet 
{
    "stage": "SHARDING_FILTER",
    "inputStage": {
        "stage": "COLLSCAN",
        "filter": {
            "$expr": {
                "$gte": [
                    "$createdTs",
                    {
                        "$subtract": [
                            "$$NOW",
                            {
                                "$const": 259200000
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "direction": "forward"
    }
},
"rejectedPlans": []
}

Comment: Explain plain without $expr
-----
"parsedQuery": {
    "createdTs": {
        "$gte": "2022-11-06T00:00:00.000Z"
    }
},
"winningPlan": {
    "stage": "SHARDING_FILTER",
    "inputStage": {
        "stage": "FETCH",
        "inputStage": {
            "stage": "IXSCAN",
            "keyPattern": {
                "createdTs": 1
            },
            "indexName": "createdTs_1",
              "indexBounds": {
                "createdTs": [
                    "[new Date(1667692800000), new Date(9223372036854775807)]"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

Based on above post, got it working in Mongo 4.4 with below command.
Dynamic view for records in last 24 hours.

```
db.createView(
   "viewname",
   "source",
   [ { $match: {$expr: { $gte: [ "modifiedTime" , { $subtract: [ "$$NOW", 24*60*60*1000 ] } ] }}}]
)
```